# Why do high voltage / low amperage shocks hurt?

Tags: voltage, safety, amperage

I learned that when electric shocks happen, the amount of danger a person is exposed to depends on the amount of current: 10mA is enough to be felt and progressively higher amperages causes muscles to contract, heart failure, etc.

Picanas and cattle prods, however, seem to operate with high voltage and low amperage, so as not to cause severe injury. Picanas even operate with as little as 1mA of current.

One difference is that the terminals are very close together when they contact the skin, but that doesn't fully explain to me how such low current suddenly becomes painful.

It's also not clear to my why voltage matters. Doesn't voltage only exist as a way to "pressure" current through the circuit? If the rate of electrons flowing through is the same, why would any level of voltage make any difference?

Comment: Your second last sentence should probably read, "Doesn't *voltage* only exist as a way to "pressure" current through the circuit?"

Comment: I have a gadget here that generates sparks at around  30 thousand Volts.  The sparks can easily jump 1cm.  It doesn't hurt to get zapped by it because there's very little charge - very little current flows, and only for a very short time.  I wouldn't touch the output of a neon light transformer, though.  The voltage is lower, but continuous, and it can deliver far more current.  That doesn't just hurt, it can kill you.  Whether it hurts or kills or just tingles is a mixture of voltage, current, and time.  Get it wrong and kiss your backside byebye.

Comment: Obviously these things use enough current for the discharge to be painful.

Comment: watts = volts X amps, so 1ma@1000v == 10ma@100v

Answer (score 3):

Dry skin isn't that conductive. You can stick your fingers on a 9V battery and feel nothing. Your tongue would be a different story though.

Check this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_shock#Body_resistance

Basically, skin resistance varies a lot depending on humidity, but also voltage and duration of exposure. If sufficient voltage and time is available, the "insulation barrier" breaks down, and you're in real trouble.

Cattle prods and other zappers have terminals in close proximity to ensure the current flows locally (which hurts) but not through the heart. High voltage is used to break the isolation barrier (it will arc through clothes or dry skin). But overall current and shock energy is very low, to make it relatively safe.

Comment: So - how does 1 mA causes great pain when the current goes a short distance through skin, but 10 mA is a "mild sensation" when going through the whole body? Shouldn't the same amount of current hurt the same amount either way? I would have thought factors such as the voltage and the length of the "body circuit" would only have indirect effect: insofar as different levels of voltage and resistance _allow more current to flow_. Same goes for voltage breaking the isolation barrier: if all that does is allow more current to flow, then how does it help when current is still held low?

Comment: 10mA isn't "mild" at all. Check the wikipedia link under "Factors in lethality of electric shock", you'll see that 2 seconds at 10mA is "muscle contraction with reversible effects" (ie you better let go of the wire before that happens and/or not fall from the ladder)...